# Android: How to change spinner background on event onItemSelected

Tags: android, spinner

I'm new to android programming and I'm trying to change the background of the correct spinner (I have several on the same activity) based on the value of the selection.

To illustrate the question let's take a very simple example. Imagine that a spinner has three items on the list: Yellow, Green and Blue. When The user selects Yellow, the spinner background should be yellow and so on.

I've done several tries but none of them worked:

1)

```
 View v = parent.getSelectedView();
 v.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);
```

doesn't change the spinner background

2)

```
v = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

getting an error from the compiler because it seems `findViewById` is not recognized inside the `CustomOnItemSelectedListener` class.

I'm a bit lost here. Any help will be welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

just change your background color statement with this line of code-

```
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

similarly any color which you want to use can use in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF") instead of 0xFFFFFF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {  
    String s = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(“yellow”))                        
        parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW); 
    ... 
}
```

Try this..,.